# Was the radical change in art in the 15th century assisted by technology?

Tags: history, technology, art

The British artist [David Hockney](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Hockney) argues in his book *[Secret Knowledge](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Secret-Knowledge-Rediscovering-techniques-Masters/dp/0500286388/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1390426908&sr=8-4&keywords=hockney)* that:

> from the early 15th century many Western artists used optics--by which I mean mirrors and lenses (or a combination of the two)--to create living projections

His basic idea is that tools like the Camera Obscura and the emerging science of optics created technological methods that allowed artists to create effects like realistic perspective.

But his views have offended some in the mainstream art world. As an Amazon review of the book reports:

> Hockney concedes that his opinions have been attacked by the mainstream art world that has complained that "for an artist to use optical aids would be 'cheating'; that somehow I was attacking the idea of innate genius".

Is Hockney's thesis convincing? Did some of the great artists use technological aids to create their masterpieces?

Comment: Is this an ad for [Tim's Vermeer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim's_Vermeer)? :-) Given it is a controversial question about art history, what sort of evidence would you find convincing?

Comment: @Oddthinking Tim's Vermeer triggered the question by reminding me of the original Hockney argument, but actually the movie makes an even stronger claim which might merit a different question. This one is just aimed at the idea that some tech (mirrors, lenses etc) was used. I'm convinced; why are art historians not also convinced? Are there good argument against? I'd accept evidence of non-technology approaches that generate the same effects, if plausible.

Comment: Maybe it is a matter of history, not possibility of using any tech, that "mainstream" art historians reject the hypothesis. With a rewording, the history.se site might be able to give you some helpful information. At that time, there was a radical change in everything, music, art, religion, government, science, etc. I would not be surprised if there was overlap.

Comment: @fredsbend I imagine that a question on history.se might ask related but different questions. This question (I think) works here because the core claim is that, in the absence of written documentation, many experts think they can see evidence of technological assistance in artworks. That a solid scientific claim for skeptics.se. I'm sure we could debate related claims on history.se, but the scientific claim fits here.

Comment: @matt_black: Hockney's tried to imply that artists used a technique which, from a practical perspective, simply doesn't work, and discredited the notion that painters used optical devices.  I would think that an art historian whose view wasn't clouded by Hockney's fallacious theory should find *Tim's Vermeer* compelling.  Good artists (or even minimally-competent ones) can render perspective without optical devices, but people are *biologically incapable* of judging tonal shifts over a large area without optical assistance.  An artist with a Vermeer painting might experiment to see...

Comment: ...what would be necessary to match the colors therein, and thus learn what shades of color should be used to paint walls in other scenes, but someone somewhere must have used some measurement apparatus to detect differences in lightness caused by variations in illumination.

Comment: @supercat Hockney identified (convincingly I think) that *something* had changed art most likely emerging technology of the time. He experimented with camera obscure for some things. But when he saw the extra ideas (basically lens+mirrors) used in Tim's Vermeer, he was convinced this was a more complete description of the technology. And the results shown using the technique in the movie are *very* convincing.

Comment: @matt_black: The notion that *something* changed around that era is non-controversial.  The question of what drove the change is what.  The idea that the change was driven by artists using Hockney's unworkable techniques seems dubious at best.  Far more likely would be that the change was driven more by the spread of copies of new styles of artwork, than by the popularity of new apparatus.  Someone who has never seen a picture where someone who is a certain distance from the observer is drawn twice as big as someone who is twice as far away would have no idea how profoundly such...

Comment: ...a picture would be able to engage a viewer's sense of depth, but once anyone had such pictures it wouldn't take long for copies of them to spread and have a profound effect on the art world.

Answer (score 2):

It's a currently unproven issue without a clear-cut answer

- there is no direct historical evidence
- there is controversial evidence obtained by providing some mechanism which could have worked

[Prof. Charles Falco](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_M._Falco) claims to have proven it via optical methods, but [David Stork](http://www.webexhibits.org/hockneyoptics/post/stork.html) rejects the claim. That there is no historical evidence is my own assumption, since if it was presented, it would trump any discussion how the paintings could have been made.

> When David Hockney wrote in his book Secret Knowledge that he had “rediscovered” secret methods of the great painters, asserting that “from the early 15th century many Western artists used optics—by which I mean mirrors and lenses (or a combination of the two)—to create living projections,” he sparked a debate that would motivate new lines of inquiry and research in a multitude of disciplines including art history, optics, image analysis, and more. Charles Falco later claimed he had proven Hockney’s ﬁndings scientiﬁcally. In the last three “Artful Media” articles, David Stork presented applications of computer imaging for analyzing paintings, some of which challenge those claims. In this article, Falco defends his original ﬁndings.

http://fp.optics.arizona.edu/SSD/art-optics/papers/IEEEComputerVision.pdf

For more information, the wikipedia page on [the Hockney-Falco thesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockney%E2%80%93Falco_thesis) does a good job of describing the controversy.

Comment: There certainly exists evidence that it is possible to produce paintings of very good quality without use of optical apparatus since there are artists alive today who routinely do precisely that.  Further, the quality of perspective rendering that can be achieved using tools like rulers will often be just as good--if not better--than what could be done merely by tracing an optical projection.  Even if it's not possible to show what artists used hundreds of years ago, it's certainly possible to show what they don't require today.